# How to generate secure PDF reports from iReport?

Tags: security, pdf, jasper-reports, adobe, ireport

I am generating reports using iReport Designer which are exported as PDFs. It has been requested that reports be secured from copying text, editing, et cetera. How can I do this either in iReport itself or using the jasperreports library package?

This [example PDF](http://www.assenagon.com/WebReporting/doDownload?fileId=1093) is how I want the PDFs to be secured. I realize that using different operating systems/PDF viewers can easily circumvent these securities, but I still need them to satisfy this request.

Note: I do NOT want to pay for an Adobe certification subscription to get these securities. Especially since it is paying for false security.

I would also like to avoid password authentication to open documents. As in the example PDF, anyone can open and view, only copying & editing are disabled.

I am aware of the options under "Tools" > "Options" > "Export Options" tab > "PDF". I've tried selecting various permissions, added 128 bit key encryption (same as example PDF), and added an owner password. This has not worked. Here I would note that for some reason the properties in the "JasperReports Properties" tab do not change to match the export options.

For example, "net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.encrypted" property is set to false. When pdf encryption is selected in the Export Options, this does not change to true. I manually changed this on my iReport, I was unable to open any generated reports and the restore defaults was not working. I had to reinstall iReports to fix this, so just beware if you try to change those properties.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypted PDF in JasperReports (I have tested in version 6)
**Simple Code**

```
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
  configuration.setEncrypted(true);
  configuration.set128BitKey(true);
  configuration.setUserPassword("jasper");
  configuration.setOwnerPassword("reports");
  configuration.setPermissions(PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);
  exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
```

[REFER Link](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/pdfencrypt/index.html)